# Read environment variable in MAria DB query

Tags: environment-variables, mariadb

I cannot find this in the Maria DB documentation ( maybe it does not exist at all ) but is htere a way I can load an environment variable in a query?

For instance :

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Users.Name = LOAD_ENV_VAR('USER');
```

I know I can quickly do the same from any programming language, but I am curious to know whether I can do it directly in a query itself.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL and MariaDB have very few hooks to the outside world.

You can get the "user" that is logged into MariaDB with the function `USER()`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html However, that is not necessarily the same as the login to the operating system.